# matching values across columns

Tags: r, dataframe, match

Suppose I have  data frame and I want to see if each given value in a given column equals the value in the next row of a second column?

I can do it for 1 match, but I'm trying to do it for the whole data frame:

```
 match(dataset$co1[i], dataset$co1[i+1]) # where i is a given row #
```

Test dataset:

```
case <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A" ,"B", "C", "B", "A")
col1 <- c(1, 100, 50, 600, 29, 72, 7, 64, 15, 85)
col2 <- c(600, 7, 64, 29, 57, 85, 12, 82, 71, 34)
dataset <- data.frame(case, col1, col2)
```

I'd also like to do this BY case.  I was trying to see if I could put the match line in a by statement, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to index along a column.

Any advice?

Comment: I'm confused about the expected output for the example. There are no rows where a match would be found here, right?

Comment: You meant to say `match(dataset$col1[i], dataset$col2[i+1])` right?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if you find it helpful:)

Answer (score 0):

As @Frank pointed out, based on your matching condition and your provided dataset, there would not be any matches. So for demonstrative purposes, I have modified your dataset to show that my solution really works. Here is a simple way using dplyr:

```
# Modified dataset
case <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A" ,"B", "C", "B", "A")
col1 <- c(1, 100, 50, 600, 29, 72, 7, 64, 15, 85)
col2 <- c(600, 7, 64, 1, 600, 85, 100, 82, 71, 34)
dataset <- data.frame(case, col1, col2)
> dataset
   case col1 col2
1     A    1  600
2     B  100    7
3     C   50   64
4     A  600    1
5     A   29  600
6     A   72   85
7     B    7  100
8     C   64   82
9     B   15   71
10    A   85   34
```

Notice that I changed the 4th row of col2 to 1, 5th row to 600 and the 7th row to 100. This way the 4th row of col2 would match with 1st of col1, 5th of col2 matches with 4th of col1, and the 7th of col2 matches with 2nd of col1 when *matching by case*. Furthermore, only 5th row of col2 would match with 4th of col1 when *not* matching by case.

```
library(dplyr)
dataset %>% 
  add_rownames() %>%
  mutate(col2 = lead(col2)) %>%
  filter(col1 == col2)

# A tibble: 1 × 4
  rowname   case  col1  col2
    <chr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1       4      A   600   600
```

This code returns the rows of col1 that matches with the following row of col2. I added `add_rownames()` so that you know its original row index in `dataset`. The `lead()` function in `mutate()` is simply the opposite of `lag()` in `dplyr` (The generic `lag()` in base R does not allow lagging non-timeseries vectors). It "lags" col2 by `k = -1`.

```
dataset %>% 
  add_rownames() %>%
  group_by(case) %>%
  mutate(col2 = lead(col2)) %>%
  filter(col1 == col2)

Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: case [2]

  rowname   case  col1  col2
    <chr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1      A     1     1
2       2      B   100   100
3       4      A   600   600
```

By adding `group_by()`, you can do the same thing, but by "case". As you can see, it returns the matching rows as expected.

If you don't want to use `dplyr` for some reason, here is a more generic solution:

```
## No group by case
# Lag col2 (Call the lagged column col3)
dataset$col3 = c(dataset$col2[-1], NA)

dataset$match = mapply(function(x, y) match(x, y, nomatch = FALSE), 
                       dataset$col1, dataset$col3)

> dataset[dataset$match == 1,]
  case col1 col2 col3 match
4    A  600    1  600     1

## Group by case
# Split dataset into groups
dataList = split(dataset, case)

dataMatched = lapply(dataList, function(x){
  x$col2 = c(x$col2[-1], NA)
  x$match = mapply(function(x, y) match(x, y, nomatch = FALSE), 
            x$col1, x$col2)
  return(x)
})
```

Resulting list/dataframe:

```
> dataMatched
$A
   case col1 col2 match
1     A    1    1     1
4     A  600  600     1
5     A   29   85     0
6     A   72   34     0
10    A   85   NA     0

$B
  case col1 col2 match
2    B  100  100     1
7    B    7   71     0
9    B   15   NA     0

$C
  case col1 col2 match
3    C   50   82     0
8    C   64   NA     0

> unsplit(dataMatched, case)
   case col1 col2 match
1     A    1    1     1
2     B  100  100     1
3     C   50   82     0
4     A  600  600     1
5     A   29   85     0
6     A   72   34     0
7     B    7   71     0
8     C   64   NA     0
9     B   15   NA     0
10    A   85   NA     0
```